# Should a unit of work consist of multiple dbcontext

Tags: repository-pattern, dbcontext, unit-of-work

is it a good practice or common scenario that an unit of work implementation contain multiple dbcontext ? if it does, how the commit and rollback can be managed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have multiple dbcontext of the same database in a UoW because you will find concurrency and data inconsistency problems, and thats the sense of UoW, avoid this kind of issues.

A UoW can contain multiple dbcontexts of different databases but if you need atomic tasks involving two or more dbcontext you need some distributed transaction mechanism.

As I don't know the implementation tech I can not be more specific.